# How to find consecutive elements in an array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int countconsecutive (const string a[], int n);
Return the number of sequences of one or more consecutive identical items in a.
    string d[9] = {
    "ben", "chris", "polo", "polo", "donald", "donald", "donald", "marco", "marco"
};
    int p = countRuns(d, 9);  //  returns 5


//  The five sequences of consecutive identical items are
       //    "ben"
       //    "chris"
       //    "polo", "polo"
       //    "donald", "donald", "donald"
       //    "marco", "marco"
```

Do I basically have to create a if statement within a for loop that test equality between two position within the array?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: That or use [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find), `auto i = std::adjacent_find(begin(d), end(d));`.

Comment: @GuyGreer given his `string` is actually `std::string` or at least a similar value-based operator== binds to it, that is.

Comment: @decltype_auto I considered mentioning that, but decided not to.  You are correct though, and sometimes he will have to pass a functor manually to set the condition he wants.

Comment: @GuyGreer: One more reason to thank the committee for introducing lambda expressions.  :)

Comment: @decltype_auto Indeed ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `std::adjacent_find` that I mentioned in the comments.

```
#include <algorithm>

int countconsecutives(const string * a, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    auto end = a + n; //std::begin and std::end won't work with pointers
    auto i = std::adjacent_find(a, end);
    while(i != end)
    {
        count++;
        i = std::adjacent_find(i, end);
    }

    return count;
}
```

The really nice thing about using the standard algorithms is that you get 99% of your edge case handling for free (100% in this case).  This already works with empty arrays and arrays of length 1.  Moreover, if you want to change it to some other type that is equality comparable you can just change the string to a template and everything still just works (though part of that is from the use of `auto`).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use standard algorithm `std::adjacent_find` or write appropriate loops yourself.

For example.

**Using standard algorithm std::adjacent_find**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

size_t countconsecutive( const std::string a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t cnt = 0;

    for ( auto first = a; first != a + n; first == a + n ? first : ++first )
    {
        ++cnt;
        first = std::adjacent_find( first, a + n, std::not_equal_to<std::string>() );
    }

    return cnt;
}    

int main()
{
    std::string a[] = 
    {
        "ben", "chris", "polo", "polo", "donald", "donald", "donald", "marco", "marco"
    };

    std::cout << countconsecutive( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Using ordinary loops**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

size_t countconsecutive( const std::string a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t cnt = 0;

    for ( auto first = a; first != a + n; ++first )
    {
        ++cnt;

        for ( auto next = first; ++next != a + n && *first == *next; ++first );  
    }

    return cnt;
}    

int main()
{
    std::string a[] = 
    {
        "ben", "chris", "polo", "polo", "donald", "donald", "donald", "marco", "marco"
    };

    std::cout << countconsecutive( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the both cases the output is

```
5
```

Comment: What is the point of `first == a + n ? first : ++first`? `first` cannot be `a + n` or the loop would have terminated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about whether your array is somewhat reshuffled, you could use `std::unique` to do all the work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string a[] = 
    {
        "ben", "chris", "polo", "polo", "donald", "donald", "donald", "marco", "marco"
    };

    std::cout << std::distance(a, std::unique(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you do, you could use `std::unique_copy`, but that clearly involves some performance penalty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string a[] = 
    {
        "ben", "chris", "polo", "polo", "donald", "donald", "donald", "marco", "marco"
    };


    std::vector<std::string> unique_elements;
    std::unique_copy(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), std::back_inserter(unique_elements));
    std::cout << unique_elements.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And what answer is complete without an elegant `boost` implementation?

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/adjacent_filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/size.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::string a[] = 
    {
        "ben", "chris", "polo", "polo", "donald", "donald", "donald", "marco", "marco"
    };


    std::cout << boost::size(a | boost::adaptors::adjacent_filtered(std::not_equal_to<std::string>()));

    return 0;
}
```